# result inconsistency in python

Tags: python, substring

I have two text files and the content are as under (`file1.txt` and `file2.txt` respectively);

```
MKKVEAIIRPFKLDEVKIALVNAGIVGMTVSEVRGFGRQKGQTERYRGSEYTVEFLQKLKVEIVVEDNQVDMVVDKIIAAARTGEIGDGKIFISPVEQVIRIRTGEKNTEAV
```

and

```
AQTVPYGIPLIKADKVQAQGYKGANVKVGIIDTGIAASHTDLKVVGGASFVSGESYNTDGNGHGTHVAGTVAALDNTTGVLGVAPNVSLYAIKVLNSSGSGTYSAIVSGIEWATQNGLDVINMSLGGPSGSTALKQAVDKAYASGIVVVAAAGNSGSSGSQNTIGYPAKYDSVIAVGAVDSNKNRASFSSVGAELEVMAPGVSVYSTYPSNTYTSLNGTSMASPHVAGAAALILSKYPTLSASQVRNRLSSTATNLGDSFYYGKGLINVEAAAQ
```

I need to fetch the character based on the index of this string which I know. Now, I need to fetch the 20 characters before the value of the index and 20 characters after the value of index which makes a total of 41 characaters (including the character of the index). 
Here is my code

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    x = 50
    data=myfile.read()
    str1 = data[x:x+1+20]
    temp = data[x-20:x]
    print temp+str1
```

The output of `file1.txt` one is `SEVRGFGRQKGQTERYRGSEYTVEFLQKLKVEIVVEDNQVD` which is correct.

The problem is if I run the same code on `file2.txt` and change the index (value of x) to `56`, the output I should be getting is `AASHTDLKVVGGASFVSGESYNTDGNGHGTHVAGTVAALDN`. Instead I am getting `ASHTDLKVVGGASFVSGESYNTDGNGHGTHVAGTVAALDNT`
Why is this?

Comment: @DanielLee I did, yes

Comment: Your problem is that you have problem expressing what you want. Do you want the text to give you the 41 character chain that has in its center the 56th character of your string?  If so you should use x=55 and not 56

Comment: Can not reproduce. As a side note, you should add a check whether `x < 20`, otherwise you will get funny results when the `from` position of the slice is negative.

Comment: It is because index starts from 0 and not 1. That is why your result is shifted to right by 1. Python is not inconsistent, your counting is.

Comment: @Wajahat, Then how come I am getting correct results from file one?

Comment: How do you know if it is the correct result? I have counted and both results are consistent.

Comment: @Wajahat, It is the correct result. You can run the program and check it for yourself. 20 characters before the index, index, and 20 characters after the index. This is the correct output from file1. My question is, If Im having correct output from file1, how come its giving me wrong result when I am using file2?

Comment: Looks like I will have to post a picture and show you what I mean.

Comment: If you think that would be helpful, please do share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so if you check, index 50 in file 1 (first row) is `Y`, 20 elements from left start from `SEV...` which means starting from index 30. This is your result for file1, which you say is correct.

```
M   K   K   V   E   A   I   I   R   P   F   K   L   D   E   V   K   I   A   L   V   N   A   G   I   V   G   M   T   V   S   E   V   R   G   F   G   R   Q   K   G   Q   T   E   R   Y   R   G   S   E   Y   T   V   E   F   L   Q   K   L   K   V   E   I   V   V   E   D   N   Q   V   D   M   V   V   D   K   I   I   A   A   
A   Q   T   V   P   Y   G   I   P   L   I   K   A   D   K   V   Q   A   Q   G   Y   K   G   A   N   V   K   V   G   I   I   D   T   G   I   A   A   S   H   T   D   L   K   V   V   G   G   A   S   F   V   S   G   E   S   Y   N   T   D   G   N   G   H   G   T   H   V   A   G   T   V   A   A   L   D   N   T   T   G   V   
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
```

Now, for file2 (second row), you set index to `56` which is `N` in file 2, and 20 elements from left starts from `ASH...`, starting from index 36. This is the expected result, I don't see why are you saying it is wrong.

Third row represents the index number

Also see image below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Answer is now marked.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = data[x-20:x]
```

will give you

```
temp = data[36:56]
```

i.e. the characters 36 to 55 (included) of your string

the string starts at character 0, so data[36] is indeed your second A, i.e. the 37th character of your string

No bug here, just a counter issue

you probably actually would want to set x = 55 (i.e. the middle character is the 56th of your string, because it has the index of 55, since indexing starts at zero in python)

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    x = 50
    data=myfile.read()
    print data[x-20:x+21]
```

This takes a slice from position x-20 to position x+21. This will give you a slice of 41 chars.

data2, 56 returns:
`ASHTDLKVVGGASFVSGESYNTDGNGHGTHVAGTVAALDNT` - Your code is correct.